# Calling a button click that is wrapped in another html tag inside an html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Just a quick question here. How can I call a click event of a button that is wrapped inside another html tag inside a main html page?

Sample code below is copied from a Dynamics CRM page source and the second html tag is inserted as a web resource on a Dynamics CRM form.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            //alert("first ready ...");

            //alert($("#btnHangup"));

            $("#btnHangup").click();

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-crm-Field-Data-Print" colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="" visible="false">
                <div class="ms-crm-Field-Data-Print" style="" data-height="48" colspan="2" rowspan="2" id="WebResource_Hangup_d">
                    <span>
                        <iframe frameborder="0" id="WebResource_Hangup" onload="if(!IsNull(Mscrm.InlineIFrameControlView)) Mscrm.InlineIFrameControlView.loadHandler(&quot;WebResource_Hangup&quot;)" class="ms-crm-Custom-Read" style="border: 0px; visibility: visible; display: block;" tabindex="0" url="/5Um2/%7B635594134590000132%7D/WebResources/cc_HangupButtonWebResource?orglcid=1033&amp;orgname=15Um2&amp;userlcid=1033&amp;type=10006&amp;typename=cc_&amp;id=" src="/_static/blank.htm" iswebresource="True" scrolling="no">
                            #document
                            <html>
                            <head>
                                <meta charset="utf-8">
                                <meta>
                                <meta>
                                <meta>
                                <meta>
                                <meta>
                                <meta>
                                <meta>
                                <meta>
                                <meta>
                            </head>
                            <body style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                                <title></title>
                                <script src="../WebResources/ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript" script=""></script>
                                <script type="text/javascript" src="/15Um2/_common/global.ashx?ver=-860134328"></script>
                                <script type="text/javascript" src="/15Um2/_common/windowinformation/windowinformation.js.aspx?lcid=1033&amp;ver=-860134328"></script>
                                <script type="text/javascript" src="/15Um2/_common/entityproperties/entitypropertiesutil.js.aspx?tstamp=100732643&amp;ver=-860134328"></script>
                                <script src="../WebResources/cc__wizard" type="text/javascript"></script>
                                <link href="../WebResources/cc_Style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                                <script src="../WebResources/cc_jquery_163" type="text/javascript"></script>
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input class="hangup-btn" title="Click to hangup" id="btnHangUp" style="width: 110px;" type="button" value="Hangup">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(document).ready(function () {
                                        $("#btnHangUp").click(function () {
                                            alert("hangup clicked");
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                            </body>
                        </html>
                    </iframe>
                </span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot have nested `html` tags, so your code is invalid. If you check the page in a DOM inspector you'll see that the second `html` tag (and likely also the `head` and `body` tags) will have been removed.

Comment: There's also no `tabe` element in HTML, and `<meta>` on its own is invalid, ...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan However embedded web resource in a Dynamics CRM form is producing this source code. No choice then?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh I am sorry. The html tag is nested inside a div > span > and a iframe inside a parent page. Apologies.

Comment: @Ali.NET: You're saying that the second `ready` is in an `iframe`? That ***really*** changes the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I got it. I have updated the code above now. Though it is now not executing as a separate piece of code as a normal html page. May be due to `iframe` part? But this is the pattern of the code inside the html source of dynamics crm page.

Answer (score 1):

Your code in the main page is looking for `#btnHangup` **in that document**, but it's not in that document, it's in the document associated with the `iframe`.

For the rest of this answer I'm going to assume you can't change the contents of the `iframe`, as seems to be suggested by your comments on the question.

To trigger a click on the element, you'll need to:

1. Wait for the `iframe` to load
2. Retrieve the element from the `iframe`'s document
3. Trigger the click on that element

So I would do something like this (see comments):

```
// When our document is ready...
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Try to do the click
    tryClick();

    function tryClick() {
        var frame, button, jqFrame;

        // Get the frame
        frame = $("#WebResource_Hangup")[0];

        // If we have it and it has its document...
        if (frame && frame.contentDocument && frame.contentWindow) {
            // Inject jQuery into it if we haven't
            jqFrame = frame.contentWindow.jQuery;
            if (!jqFrame) {
                $("script[src*=jquery]").clone().appendTo(frame.contentWindow);
            } else {
                // We have, hook up a ready handler
                jqFrame(frame.contentDocument).ready(function() {
                    // Fire the click
                    jqFrame("#btnHangup").click();
                });

                // Done
                return;
            }
        }

        // If we get here, we haven't hooked up the ready handler,
        // so try again in a moment
        setTimeout(tryClick, 10);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't check this solution. I found another workaround for the issue due to which I was creating this case example. Should I remove this question or leave it as it is?

Comment: @Ali.NET: You can't delete a question with an upvoted answer. If you solved the problem another way, it's perfectly fine here on SO for you to post your own answer describing what you did and accept it.